# Change dialog sequence for WixUI_Minimal in Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am creating Wix installer which will create app pool,virtual directory and doing some other settings for virtual directory. Now before it create virtual directory, I want to display a dialog to get the username and password from user and set it in App Pool. The installer already uses WixUI_Minimal to show license agreement and progress screen. I want to show my custom dialog after License screen.
How can I change the built-in sequence of WixUI_Minimal and place my dialog box?

Below is the code for the changes that I have made for the execution sequence of Wix_Minical dialog set. PoolSettingsDlg is my dialog.

**NOTE:** I am using Wix 3.9.1006.0 version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:ui="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<!--<Fragment>
<Property Id="Custom_UIMinimalCommon" Value="1" />
<UI Id="WixUI_Minimal">
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
  <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Minimal" />

  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="PoolSettingsDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
  <DialogRef Id="WelcomeDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="WelcomeEulaDlg" />

   <Publish Dialog="PoolSettingsDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="Return" >1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PoolSettingsDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="PoolSettingsDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Before="WelcomeEulaDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Show>
    <Show Dialog="WelcomeEulaDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">NOT Installed</Show>
  </InstallUISequence>

  <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
</UI>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```

-->

Comment: Have you read this one? http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain

Comment: Besides, this page in manual might be helpful: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

Comment: @YanSklyarenko   I read it but it is not giving any clear idea about the changes of UI sequence for Wix_Minimal. Please see my question again. I have placed code. It is giving so many errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WixUI_Minimal isn't a good choice for what you are trying to do because it displays 1 dialog and then exits the wizard loop.

A better approach would be to build upon the WixUI_FeatureTree experience.  You can insert a dialog after the license dialog with this XML:

```
  <!-- Insert into dialog sequencing by inserting control events on previous and next dialogs-->
      <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="YourCustomDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="YourCustomDlg" Order="3">NOT Installed</Publish>
```

FWIW, I maintain an open source project called [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com) that does this you.  It projects project visual studio project templates (scaffolding)  that has a fragment that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="UI">
      <!-- See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_index.htm for more information-->
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree"/>
      <!--Uncomment to inject a custom dialog into the install wizard loop -->
      <!--<UIRef Id="CustomDlg"/>-->
    </UI>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

You simply uncomment the UIRef line to pull in an additional fragment that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="CustomDlg">
      <Dialog Id="CustomDlg" Height="270" Width="370" Title="[ProductName] Setup">

        <!-- Header -->
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner"/>
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Text="{\WixUI_Font_Title}Custom Dialog" Transparent="yes"/>
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Text="Place your custom description here" Transparent="yes"/>
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0"/>

        <!-- Body  -->
        <Control Id="CustomLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="15" Text="Customer:" TabSkip="yes"/>
        <Control Id="Custom" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="80" Width="320" Height="18" Property="CUSTOM"/>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0"/>
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" Text="&amp;Next" TabSkip="no" Default="yes" Height="17" Width="56" X="236" Y="243">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg"/>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton"  Text="Cancel" TabSkip="no" Height="17" Width="56" X="304" Y="243" Cancel="yes">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg"/>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton"  Text="&amp;Back" TabSkip="no" Height="17" Width="56" X="180" Y="243">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg"/>
        </Control>

      </Dialog>
      <!-- Insert into dialog sequencing by inserting control events on previous and next dialogs-->
      <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomDlg" Order="3">NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Using IsWiX it's possible to create a basic installer for a desktop app, windows service and IIS web application  without typing a lick of XML.   This really helps with the learning curve.  As your skills improve you can customize by authoring additional XML.

Comment: Thanks for reply but still I cannot understand your reply. I am very new to Wix. The sequence I want is license dialog, then my own dialog, progress dialog and end dialog. Is CustomDlg mean by my  own dialog.

Comment: Now I got my custom dialog after License dialog. Now how can I change look and feel of various dialog sets like welcome screen images, License agreement content etc. Moreover I want to set properties of my dialog similar to that of in built dialog set. How can I do that?

Comment: You should accept this answer if you have it working.  Sorry, one question one answer at a time.  Ask a new question.